# Getting Project Root Path In Controller ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, path

I am using dotlesscss for my css and I remember how to use that but what I am forgetting is how to get the root project path so that I can generate the full file path to my .less file to get for the less engine to parse.  How do I get the project root path so that I can generate the path for my less files?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

```
Server.MapPath("~");
```

or:

```
HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
```

Comment: Better use `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` because `HttpContext.Current.Server` can be `null` in some circumstances -- for instance, if called from a spawned worker thread.

Comment: `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` is in the `System.Web.Hosting` namespace.

Comment: if **Server.MapPath** doesn't work. Try **System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(saveAsLocation)**

Comment: Is there any way to add this code to a Web.Config file?