# path of local file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, appharbor

I want to deploy a applicacion in appharbor, in local my app read and write a file locate in C://projects/Name_App

But in the server logically this path don't run.

How to change the path in the app to work fine in appharbor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203945/getting-project-root-path-in-controller-asp-net-mvc). Both `Server.MapPath("file.txt");` and `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Server.MapPath` method:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    string file = Server.MapPath("~/myfile.txt");
    ...
}
```