# Using a Relative Paths in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to seed my database with an image. I'm able to do this successfully using an absolute path, however this won't work as a permanent solution.

```
 Image = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Graded Unit\Implementation\YorkiesVehicleHire\YorkiesVehicleHire\Images\Ferrari488.jpg"),
```

How could I get the same path so resolve. Using something like

```
~\Images\Ferrari488.jpg
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at `Path.Combine` and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203945/getting-project-root-path-in-controller-asp-net-mvc ?

Comment: Oh the good problem with MVC applications. `~` is supposed to be pointing to `wwwroot` and yet it doesn't? VS has suddenly decided to use `IIS Express` directory instead of Project directory as home path, no? Try printing `WorkingDirectory` variable from `Environment` and it will tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting only file name from a path you can use `Path.GetFileName('path');` which in your case you can get the file name first as:

```
var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@"E:\Graded Unit\Implementation\YorkiesVehicleHire\YorkiesVehicleHire\Images\Ferrari488.jpg");
//filename will now only contain: Ferrari488.jpg

//Now let's concatenate it with ~/Images/
var storingPath= "~\Images\" + fileName;
```

Now for the absolute path, try using `Server.MapPath("~")` which returns the physical path to the root of the application.

So in your case if you want to get the absolute path for `~\Images\Ferrari488.jpg` then it will look like: `Server.MapPath("~\Images\Ferrari488.jpg");` or `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\Images\Ferrari488.jpg");`

OR

```
var absolutePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(storingPath);
Image = File.ReadAllBytes(absolutePath);
```

Comment: I still need the File.ReadAllBytes so I can convert the image to bytes to store it in the DB. Will Server.MapPath do that? I can't get the "Server" to resolve any idea what the using statement should be?

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have now got it working.                                     I used,                                                                                                                         var absolutePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\Images\");   Then,            
Image = File.ReadAllBytes(absolutePath + "Ferrari488.jpg"),    Once again Thanks for the help.

Comment: `absolutePath + "Ferrari488.jpg"` Do not do that. Use `Path.Combine`.