# How to get WebRootPath in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, npoi

I'm trying to implement this application in ASP.NET MVC 5

[**Export And Import Excel Data Using NPOI Library In .NET Core 2 Razor Pages**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-and-import-data-using-npoi-library-in-net-core-2-razor-pages/)

specifically, I'm trying this part which is to make the excel file downloadable one

[image]

So here my code for creating and downloading file

```cs
public FileResult OnPostExporttoExcel() 
{
    string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    string fileName = @"Testingdummy.xlsx";
    string URL = string.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}", Request.Scheme, Request.Host, fileName);
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(webRootPath, fileName));
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    // --- Below code would create excel file with dummy data----  
    using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(webRootPath, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
        IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        ISheet excelSheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Testingdummy");

        IRow row = excelSheet.CreateRow(0);
        row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("CustomerId");
        row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("FirstName");
        row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("LastName");
        row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Email");

        cust = from s in _context.Customers select s;
        int counter = 1;
        foreach (var customer in cust) {
            string FirstName = string.Empty;
            if (customer.FirstName.Length > 100)
                FirstName = customer.FirstName.Substring(0, 100);
            else
                FirstName = customer.FirstName;
            row = excelSheet.CreateRow(counter);
            row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(customer.CustomerId);
            row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(FirstName);
            row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(customer.LastName);
            row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(customer.Email);
            counter++;
        }
        workbook.Write(fs);
    }
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(webRootPath, fileName), FileMode.Open)) {
         fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    }
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
}
```

but I don't know how to get `_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;` in asp.net MVC 5

Comment: This link might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203945/getting-project-root-path-in-controller-asp-net-mvc